# Webpack site wont display when run through docker image

Tags: docker, webpack

I am setting up a Javascript development environment for myself. I don't know much about it but I am using `Webpack` and `Babel` in the setup. After a lot of digging through I finally got Webpack compiling and running, where I could load a simple react page.

Now I created a Dockerfile to run my work on an image. Its very basic, load the files, expose the port and run the dev server. But when I try to access the site, I get a **ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED** response. There is no errors from Webpack.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8-alpine
WORKDIR /
EXPOSE 3000
COPY . /frontend
WORKDIR /frontend
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

**Webpack.dev.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js',
        vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom', 'semantic- ui-react']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/src/dev',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '../../theme.config$': path.join(__dirname, 'src/semantic-ui/theme.config')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 100000,
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "vendor",
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/dev/index.html'),
        })
    ]
}
```

To be honest I am not sure what lot of this config file is about, as I copied it from a work colleague and made whatever tweaks were needed. But I once I got Webpack compiling and running I was happy and left it as is.

Here is the command I use to start the container `docker container run --rm -p 3000:3000 frontend`

There is no errors showing on the container from Webpack and I have exposed the ports correctly so I don't know why this isn't working or if its a docker issue or a webpack issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can go into the container with a command `docker exec -it frontend /bin/bash` to check if something is wrong.

Comment: `devserver.host: 0.0.0.0`

Comment: I tried devserver.host: 172.0.0.1 and it didn’t work, I’ll try 0.0.0.0 and see how that goes

Comment: Thanks @playMa256 that worked